# Heroku running migration rails4 and jruby

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby

I am using rails4 with jruby.
After I successfully push to heroku, my app is running. Next I needed to run the migration and I did

```
    $ heroku run rake db:migrate
    Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3257
    stty: stdin isn't a terminal
```

`stty: stdin isn't a terminal` never fades and migration never run.

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3', engine: "jruby", engine_version: "1.7.6"

gem 'rails', "4.0.0"


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
end


group :development do
  gem 'jdbc-sqlite3'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
end

group :production do
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2.2'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'rolify', git: "https://github.com/EppO/rolify.git"
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'stripe_event'

gem 'puma'

gem 'slim-rails'

gem 'protected_attributes'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require=>false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.0.1'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

How to run migration now? Also environment variables are not picked up by the application.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the jruby build pack?

https://github.com/jruby/heroku-buildpack-jruby

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks